# How to stop Win7 excessive "Connect Dial-up Connection" prompts for Bluetooth DUN?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, dial-up

I've set up bluetooth dial up networking (dun) from my windows 7 laptop via my phone.

**The Problem: Stop Prompting me already**

Whenever I start up my laptop from standby/hibernate and it's *not* connected to the internet (via wifi or ethernet) Win7 prompts me repeatedly to "connect dial up connection".

Example,  if i have 10 firefox tabs open, Win7 will prompt me 10 times to connect bluetooth DUN.

**My question**
Here's my question:
How do I say "No. And don't ask me again in the near future" ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set your Internet Options to never attempt to (automatically) make a connection to DUN:

[image: InternetOptions]

Answer (score 0):

There's only one option.  Do not setup a dial-on-demand connection.  There is no "don't prompt me for 15-minutes" option... and no way to implement that with the default windows dialer.

Comment: Could you clarify what I should do (i.e. as opposed to "not do") to get past this problem? Any specifics would help, as I don't know the details of windows networking UI.